# Why do we still not have a Software Development Recommendations SE?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, stack-exchange, site-crossover, development

Time can be saved by answering things like,

> "I have X and want to get Y. What are some development tool/libraries/framework options that can achieve this that you'd recommend?"

These kinds of questions have value, and currently lack an appropriate home. I did some checks in meta for this before asking, but I'm assuming over the years I'm not the only one whose asked something similar to this, so I apologize if my queries were left wanting.

Comment: the literal answer would be because the site you want hasn't been through the area 51 process. But I am left really unclear what site it is you want. Can you elaborate with a handful of sample questions?

Comment: Product surveys, trying to match available packages/libraries against requirements, is a miserable, unrewarding task in software development.  That's when you have the full requirement specs.  If you have not, it's just ditch-digging, where you spend all day slinging a spade and then get told that the ditch is in the wrong field.  Typically, posters do not even specify the farm:(    No thanks..

Comment: I'm perfectly happy with this being closed due to being a duplicate. I didn't know what terms to search for, clearly :) Ironically, thanks for the downvotes. I'd delete this but I can't due to it being "invested" in already.

Answer (score 8):

> I have X and want to get Y. What are some development tool/libraries/framework options that can achieve this that you'd recommend?

And SR.SE can already handle that. Your question was closed because it asked for "communication protocols", AKA: *algorithms*. You weren't looking for *software*; you were looking for approaches to solve a software problem. What you were asking for is not a thing to help you solve a problem. You're looking for general approaches to solving that problem.

Software Engineering may be a legitimate place for that, if you can make your question sufficiently specific *and* not to ask for specific libraries (or "protocols"). You're looking for an approach to solving the problem, so ask for that. Even so, because such questions tend to be very open ended even if you're being specific about your requirements, it's still likely to get closed as "Too broad".

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck The SE network isn't meant to do everything; being hostile because there are aspects that it can't do is like getting mad at a bakery that won't fry up some bacon for you.  You can consider it excessive pedantry if you want, but look at it from our view; we're trying to help guide you into maybe having a better experience, and the thanks Nicol gets is sarcasm and hostility.  You're just reinforcing that others shouldn't even do that much, just downvote, close, and move on, leaving you to figure it out on your own.

Comment: @fbueckert I'm not mad at SE. I'm annoyed by what I perceive to be pedantry and overzealous moderation. I changed very little in my originally linked-to question to get it taken off hold. After the moderator finally replied to my comment I went ahead and made it even better. That seems to align with my perception. If a couple little changes is the difference between being put on hold and being considered legitimate, being pedantic instead of offering guidance doesn't help the person asking the question.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, I apologize for being so cranky earlier.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck Well, that depends on what our purpose is.  Are we building a site full of stuff that's, "close enough"?  Or are we trying to build a lasting repository of knowledge that withstands the test of time?  The latter requires a much more strict adherence to standards.  It *looks* like pedantry and zealotry, but, really, we're trying to build a [castle out of cabinets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378863/).  Walls gotta stay up, and that means they have to meet the standards.  SoftwareRecs, especially, has to be very strict about it.

Comment: I'm all for quality standards. If the moderator had replied with the last comment they made instead of the first comment, things would have gone down differently. No one likes being casually dismissed. I'm not active in the SR community, and it seems like my question was just one more on the "slush pile". and they got a little lazy/over it when it came to guidance for fixing it.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck I don't believe they were being lazy at all; it spurred you to resolve the issues that were perceived in the comment, and that was noticed.  You put in more effort, meet the standards, and everybody's happy.  Nobody likes being casually dismissed, but neither do people like ignoring their site's rules.